# How is buffer data accessed in D3D10?

Tags: windows, directx, arduino, screenshot

Basically, I'm trying to copy the front or back buffer to a texture, grab the 1x1 mipmap level of said texture, and then spew the color of the resulting back to the Arduino to control my room's lighting. Everything else is up and running, and I've already gotten it to work via GetDC(NULL) and StretchBlt. But this was about 15FPS, and the windows GUI ran choppy.

The downsampling is just DEMANDING to be used on a GPU.

In D3D9, it seemed like there was simply GetBackBuffer() or something like that, but I see nothing similar in D3D10. And I'm not even sure it would grab anything from the windows GUI.

Questions:

-What function(s) would I use?:

-Do I need to explicitly create a swapchain beforehand?

-Would this only capture data from other D3D programs?

Okay, here's where I'm at as far as creating the texture goes But I'm not seeing anything that gets me back to textures:

```
//Create Texture
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC    tBufferDesc;
ID3D10Texture2D         *tBuffer = NULL;
DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC        iBufferSamples = {1,0};
tBufferDesc.Width       =   iScreenSizeX;
tBufferDesc.Height      =   iScreenSizeY;
tBufferDesc.MipLevels   =   0;
tBufferDesc.ArraySize   =   1;
tBufferDesc.Format      =   DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_TYPELESS;
tBufferDesc.SampleDesc  =   iBufferSamples;
tBufferDesc.Usage       =   D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
tBufferDesc.BindFlags   =   D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D10_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
tBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
tBufferDesc.MiscFlags   =   D3D10_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;

HRESULT tBufferResult = pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&tBufferDesc, NULL , &tBuffer);
hrResult(tBufferResult);

ID3D10RenderTargetView *rtBuffer;
ID3D10Resource *rsBuffer;
pDevice->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &rtBuffer, NULL);
rtBuffer->GetResource(&rsBuffer);
rsBuffer->
```

Comment: Don't you have to explicitly create a swapchain anyway?

Comment: I'm just wondering, because I'm pretty sure an explicit swap chain would just be completely blank and useless for anything outside the app. That is, if I added this to Unreal2004, it would only pick up info from UT2004 and ignore the entire windows GUI.

Comment: So I guess I don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean if you "added this to Unreal2004"? As in, if you modified the existing code?

Comment: Yes. What I'm trying to say is: If you create a swap chain in a program, isn't its capabilities limited to that program? Ergo, I wouldn't be able to store data from the main desktop?

Comment: Yes - everything will be bound to that program/window. It almost sounds like you're trying to capture another app's screen, the way fraps does.

Comment: Here is almost EXACTLY what I'm trying to do, but in C++ instead of C#, and trying to stick with the DXSDK as included in VS 2012:

[link]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274461/Very-fast-screen-capture-using-DirectX-in-Csharp[/link]

Comment: In that case, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174550(v=vs.85).aspx (you can use `IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput` to get an `IDXGIOutput` object)

Comment: That seems good. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Hasn't exactly gone well, it's an entire chain of things I have to initialize which have become more and more bizarre. I'll have to look it up more tomorrow.